# Javac error on Generic return type

Tags: java, generics

It might sound like reinvention of wheel, but I am trying to implement a map, (like `Map<K,V>`). The class has a function called `sortedKey()` which returns an `ArrayList<K>` A cut-down version of my code is below. I have included my attempts to debug inline as comments.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Map<K,V> {
    private ArrayList<Pair<K,V> > array; //Pair<K,V> is a class defined in another file.

    //returns an ArrayList(of proper type) of keys (ie, the desired function)
    public ArrayList<K> sortedKeys(){
        ArrayList<K> ret = keys(); //another method defined inside same class

        K s = ""; // error: no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<K>)
        Collections.sort(new ArrayList<String>()); //Works just fine..
        Collections.sort(ret); //Same error here..
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Any idea on why is that error showing up? Can I not have generic return types depending on the type-variable used in creation of the class? Or do I have to do something else to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks and apologies if this question has already been asked

Cajetan

Comment: Is that line really meant to say `K s = "";`?  That looks flat-out wrong, especially with the error in comments that doesn't match (i.e. mentions a `sort` invocation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the signature of [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

So the error, though it might be confusing, is right - you **can't** call sort on a list of arbitrary type; the element type must implement Comparable.

If you restrict your generic parameter to be comparable, as in:

```
public class Map<K extends Comparable<K>,V> {
    ...
```

then the call to `Collections.sort(ret)` will succeed as you expect.

Without this restriction on the generic parameter, someone could create a `Map` with a key type of something noncomparable like `Exception` - and then how do you expect poor `Collections.sort` to handle that? :)

Comment: No problem.  I often go through a similar step myself when designing generic classes - use unbounded wildcards, and only later realise that it only really makes sense for classes with certain basic properties, such as `Serializable` or `Comparable` or `Closeable`, etc.  It's good to be able to express this through the type system as well as just Javadocs.

Comment: for best results, use `K extends Comparable<? super K>`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that `K` might not be a type with an ordering.  You should declare the class as

```
public class Map<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
```

to guarantee that `K` values can be compared to other `K` values.

Comment: for best results, use `K extends Comparable<? super K>`

Comment: True in theory, but I've never seen it actually make a difference in real code.

Answer (score 0):

Well...you should provide a **comparator** or implements **comparable** by your K(whichever it may be) class.

in case of implementing comparable, Also declare class parameter like this to restrict it to contain only comparable object.

```
public class Map<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
```

Comment: for best results, use `K extends Comparable<? super K>`

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for [Collection.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) the type has to be

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

In other words, `K` has to be declared as `Comparable<K>` or `Comparable<? super K>`